# Swapping rows in matrix determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

[matrix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIY67.png)

can I directly swap row.1 with row.n and put a negative in front of the determinant or do I need to go n to n-1, then n-1 to n-2 while multiplying by -1 each time?

Comment: yes but... if (n+1) is odd, then multiply by -1, and if (n+1) is even, leave it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may swap any two rows, and the determinant will change in sign.

You could also attain a swap between row $i$ and row $j$ like so:

1. Replace row $j$ with row $i$ plus row $j$ -- no change in determinant
2. Multiply row $i$ by $-1$ -- determinant has been negated
3. Replace row $i$ with row $i$ plus row $j$ -- no additional change in determinant
4. Replace row $j$ with row $j$ minus row $i$ -- no additional change in determinant

Comment: Yes I know that, but can I swap 1st row with n'th row directly and change sign just once or do I have to first swap n and n-1 and then n-1 and n-2, changing sings each time?

Comment: You may swap **any** two rows. They don't need to be next to each other.